# How do I delete an Azure Enterprise Applications without Azure subscription?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cloud-shell

I want to remove a tenant from Azure portal.

All Enterprise applications should be deleted before the tenant removing:

[image]

There are two options how Enterprise applications could be removed:

1. **From the Azure portal.** Go to the application you want to delete, click `"Properties"`, click `"Delete"` button. This option is not available as `"Delete"` button is disabled.
2. **Using PowerShell commands with Azure Cloud Shell.** This option is not available because it states `"No valid subscription found. You need an Azure subscription to use Azure Cloud Shell"`.

I don't want to activate an Azure subscription just for the removing tenant.

But all options are useless in this case.

Any alternative approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to delete the enterprise application in the portal, make sure you logged in to the portal with the `Global admin` account.

If this still not work, try to use powershell in local(not in cloud shell).

1.Install the `AzureAD` module.

```
Install-Module -Name AzureAD
```

2.Login with `Global admin` account.

```
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId <TenantId>
```

3.Delete the enterprise application.

```
Remove-AzureADServicePrincipal -ObjectId <app objectid got from the portal>
```